# HttpWebRequest times out with multiple network adaptors enabled

Tags: c#, networking, httpwebrequest

On my Win7 PC I have a couple of virtual network adaptors that are used for VMWare server.
My HttpWebRequest times out when I have these adaptors enabled. Should I really have to tell it which adaptor to bind to?

```
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url.AbsoluteUri + "etc.txt");
            request.Timeout = 2000;

            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    return reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
```

**UPDATE**

I'm guessing this is a common issue. Does anybody have a standard way to handle this? I cant really prompt the user for the interface as they are non tech. Rohit's answer is good start at showing how to set the ServicePoint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tim, If you are seeing timeout it is because your new adapters have route for the URL and they are not reaching the destination.

```
public delegate IPEndPoint BindIPEndPoint(ServicePoint servicePoint, IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint, int retryCount);
```

You can use it as

```
private IPEndPoint BindIPEndPointCallback(ServicePoint servicePoint,IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint, int retryCount)
{
    if(retryCount < 3)
        return new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.10.60"), 0); 
    else
        return new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
}
```

and...

```
 HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
 req.ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate =  new BindIPEndPoint(BindIPEndPointCallback);
```

See http://www.netbrick.net/blog/PermaLink,guid,b9c255d9-74b4-45ab-8fd0-c9a04784655a.aspx for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from Rohits answer. Would this work well at trying all the adaptors?

```
    private IPEndPoint BindIPEndPointCallback(ServicePoint servicePoint, IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint, int retryCount)
    {
        List<IPEndPoint> endPoints = new List<IPEndPoint>();

        foreach (NetworkInterface netinface in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
        {
            foreach (IPAddressInformation unicast in netinface.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
            {
                if(unicast.Address.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                    endPoints.Add(new IPEndPoint(unicast.Address, 80));
            }
        }

        if (retryCount > endPoints.Count - 1)
            return new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 80);
        else
            return endPoints[retryCount];
    }
```